# Can "model" be treated as special controller property in EmberJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have 3 related questions;

**Q1:** 
In EmberJS, can "model" be treated as special controller property.

I am saying this, coz consider for a controller (has model returning firstName & lastName attributes), I have a property "isVisible"

So in the template, I would say

```
{{#if isVisible}}
Hello {{model.firstName}}, {{model.lastName}}
{{/if}}
```

Now here, "isVisible" is controller property and referred directly, whereas to display firstName/lastName, we say model.firstName & model.lastName

So that makes it seem like "model" is some kind of special property defined on the controller somewhat similar to "isVisible"

**Q2:**
Also, I assume the model's value would always be returned by the corresponding route's model hook. Not sure if there are many other ways ?

**Q3:**
Also is "model" a special/reserved keyword which Ember recognizes. I am asking this, coz I have observed

```
self.controllerFor('someroute').get('model.someParam')
```

It would be great if you could point the Ember library code for get/set where Ember handles this "model" keyword.

Answer (score 2):

**A1:**`model` property is not special property of controller, it might appear special because it is automatically/(behind the scenes) set by `route` in [setupController()](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_setupController) method, you can override it and use other property name for model instead

```
setupController(controller, model) {
  controller.set('person', model);
}
```

and in your template:

```
{{#if isVisible}}
Hello {{person.firstName}}, {{person.lastName}}
{{/if}}
```

now you have model set to property `person` instead of `model` in controller

**A2:** as `model` in controller is just property set by route, you can set/change it from anywhere in application (though that would be bad practise), right place to set models/data to controller is [setupController()](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_setupController) hook in route (shown above).

**A3:** *model* is not reserved keyword

Comment: Thanks...on the 3rd answer, if model is not special or recognized by EMber library...how does .get('model.someParam') work ?

Comment: as said above model property was set by `route` behind the scenes so you got `model` property  if you override `setupController` of route with empty function which does nothing you will see that `model` property won't exist in in corresponding controller so `.get('model.someParam')` will return `undefined`

Comment: Ok cool...just one more question...so what exactly does get() take or work with...i mean what kind of arguments ?

Comment: Instances of all Ember classes/factories have method `get()` (also `set()`) it is just primitive methods to work with objects, so `get()` expects just property (which you want to get) name as string, it also allows instead of writing `.get('model').get('someParam')` to do `get('model.somParam')`

Comment: Anything that extends `Ember.Object`, http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html.  Additionally you can use `Ember.get(anyObj, 'nested,path.to.property')` and `Ember.set(anyObj, 'propertyName', 'propertyValue')`